# I've removed Firefox but keep getting prompts for English language pack

Tags: firefox, 16.04, language-support

I've uninstalled Firefox, but keep getting *English language pack for Firefox* offered to me via the updater. Is there a way to make sure this never happens again?

I just checked languages under system settings and applied English (United Kingdom) system-wide. Will that do it? If so, I'll leave this here to possibly help others in the future.

Comment: You can safely uninstall the language pack. Try `sudo apt-get remove firefox-locale-[your version]` . If removing this would happen to remove other packages that depend on the language pack, it will tell you so and you can cancel the removal.

Comment: Please allow me to post this as an answer, and please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Running `sudo apt autoremove` gets rids of no longer needed dependencies, it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 5):

To remove all locales:

```
sudo apt-get remove 'firefox-locale-*'
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the language packs are separate packages that do not get uninstalled if you uninstall Firefox. However, you can safely uninstall the language pack.

Just do `sudo apt-get remove firefox-locale-[your version]`.

If removing this would happen to remove other packages that depend on the language pack, it will tell you so and you can cancel the removal. But I'm quite sure it won't.

Answer (score 0):

### How to remove installed locales?

First, we need to know the installed locales and then remove them.

#### List installed firefox locales

```
apt list --installed | grep -i "firefox-locale"
```

#### Remove firefox locales

Use `firefox-locale-[language]` to remove a package. Example:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox-locale-es
```

- `firefox-locale-es`: is a language package, this case removes the Spanish (es) package.

**IMPORTANT** `--purge` option removes user configs related to this package, except your home dir configs. If you are not sure about it, remove `--purge` from command.

### How to get all locales available for your distribution

```
apt search firefox-locale
```

[Original answer on ubuntuforums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2361094&s=6c2bee47698b7a8d62dcc3c5a72746b0&p=13644295#post13644295)